# Visual Studio 2022/AWS Toolkit: possible to show Secrets Manager in AWS Explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, asp.net-core

As a newbie to Visual Studio 2022's Amazon Web Service (AWS) Toolkit, I was surprised to see that Secrets Manager does not show up in the AWS Explorer panel:

[image]

Is there a way to make it show?  It would certainly streamline my development experience if this were the case.

If this is not possible: is anyone aware of the AWS's reasoning behind their decision not to include this functionality?  Isn't it logical to imagine that developers should be able to handle *all (or at least most)* AWS-related work within the Visual Studio environment without having to switch back and forth between VS and the AWS web portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is still an open [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues/57).